# Facebook Send Api - reactivate webhook subscription

Tags: webhooks, facebook-webhooks, facebook-send-api

My server went offline for a day and now facebook has stopped sending requests to my webhook. This is the error message i get:

Your Webhooks subscription for callback URL https://myurl has not been accepting updates for the past 0 minutes. This subscription has been disabled. To reactivate, just make a POST request with the same parameters or visit the Webhooks tab in the app dashboard. Scopri di più about Webhooks.

What post request is he talking about? i went to webhooks tab but doesnt seem to have any effect. Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Review https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started. The `POST` is how to do it automatically via `app/subscriptions` in the API; you can also configure it in the Webhooks tab manually. (It's more than just *visiting* the tab.)

Comment: ok but what should i do on that tab? i have a select with these values 

Page
Native Components
Permissions
Application
Instagram
Certificate Transparency

and a edit subscription button. i edited subscription e successfully verified the endpoin url with the token but im still not receiving post requests when users write in the chat

Comment: Same thing you did the first time when you set it all up. The "Configuring the Webhooks Product" bit of the docs I linked you has a step-by-step.

Comment: i have a select with these values Page Native Components Permissions Application Instagram Certificate Transparency and a edit subscription button. i edited subscription e successfully verified the endpoin url with the token but im still not receiving post requests when users write in the chat

Comment: You have to subscribe to specific events. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook/ Again, this is something you or another dev on your team has already done once.

Answer (score 0):

Just send this post request after adding your messenger app access token:

```
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=[MESSENGER_ACCESS_TOKEN]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Send POST request with your access token and subscribed_fields.

[https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN_here]&subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,message_deliveries,message_reads](https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=%5BACCESS_TOKEN_here%5D&subscribed_fields=messages,messaging_postbacks,messaging_optins,message_deliveries,message_reads)

Also, you can do this manually at the https://developers.facebook.com/
by checking "Subscription Fields"